# How to read Whatsapp email file in R?

Tags: r

Whatsapp has an option to email the group conversation to yourself. I did that and now want to explore it in R. The problem is that it seems to have multiple separators which I don't know how to handle in R.
Here is what I tried:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
> gf <- read_delim('df.txt', col_names = F, skip = 2, delim='\t')
Warning message:
15 problems parsing 'df.txt'. See problems(...) for more details. 
> head(gf)
Source: local data frame [6 x 12]

       X1       X2                           X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12
1  9:14pm  Mar 31                  umair: Great       NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA
2  9:14pm  Mar 31              umair: I am back       NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA
3  9:15pm  Mar 31                     umair: ??       NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA
4 10:27pm  Mar 31      umair: Kon kon zinda hay       NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA
5 10:49pm  Mar 31   Kazim: Sab zinda hain .....       NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA
6 10:50pm  Mar 31              umair: Very good       NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Can you help me read this file so that the **"sender:message"** is separated into 2 columns? And the first 2 columns are read as separate columns as shown. Obviously I don't want columns X4 to X12.

## Edit:

Here are the first few lines of the raw file:

```
9:14pm, Mar 31 - umair: Great
9:14pm, Mar 31 - umair: I am back
9:15pm, Mar 31 - umair: 
10:27pm, Mar 31 - umair: Kon kon zinda hay
10:49pm, Mar 31 - Kazim: Sab zinda hain .....
10:50pm, Mar 31 - umair: Very good
10:52pm, Mar 31 - umair: Abid agaya dobara?
10:54pm, Mar 31 - Kazim: Nai wo nai aya
10:54pm, Mar 31 - umair: Hmmmmmmmmm
```

Comment: Add sample file. May be first few lines of `df.txt`

Comment: You could use `separate()` from the `tidyr` package or `cSplit()` from the `splitstackshape` package to separate sender and message. If you want to combine X1 and X2, you could use `unite()`. If you do not want to have X4-X12, you could simply drop the columns.

Comment: Great. I think you have something like this. I leave the following as a reference. `separate(gf, X3, c("sender", "message"), sep = ": ") %>% unite(date, X1, X2, sep = " ") %>% select(1:3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is old, yet when I wanted to do the same thing, my google search lead me here. I figured it out and put it into an R package. Install and read in the data:

```
devtools::install_github("JBGruber/rwhatsapp")
library(rwhatsapp)
gf <- rwa_read("df.txt")
```

Or you can directly paste in the lines

```
> lines <- c(
  "9:14pm, Mar 31 - umair: Great",
  "9:14pm, Mar 31 - umair: I am back",
  "9:15pm, Mar 31 - umair:  ",
  "10:27pm, Mar 31 - umair: Kon kon zinda hay",
  "10:49pm, Mar 31 - Kazim: Sab zinda hain .....",
  "10:50pm, Mar 31 - umair: Very good",
  "10:52pm, Mar 31 - umair: Abid agaya dobara?",
  "10:54pm, Mar 31 - Kazim: Nai wo nai aya",
  "10:54pm, Mar 31 - umair: Hmmmmmmmmm"
)
> rwa_read(lines)
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  time                author text                
  <dttm>              <fct>  <chr>               
1 2018-03-31 21:14:13 umair  Great               
2 2018-03-31 21:14:13 umair  I am back           
3 2018-03-31 21:15:13 umair  " "                 
4 2018-03-31 22:27:13 umair  Kon kon zinda hay   
5 2018-03-31 22:49:13 Kazim  Sab zinda hain .....
6 2018-03-31 22:50:13 umair  Very good           
7 2018-03-31 22:52:13 umair  Abid agaya dobara?  
8 2018-03-31 22:54:13 Kazim  Nai wo nai aya      
9 2018-03-31 22:54:13 umair  Hmmmmmmmmm
```